# Orthogonal projection of point onto line/plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Upon looking through the definitions of different types of projections in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I stumbled upon the definition of orthogonal projection of a point onto a line/plane. The textbook gives the following statement but does not provide a proof of it: given a point $P$ and a line or plane $l\text{/}\pi$ there exists exactly one point $P^{\prime}\in l\text{/}\pi$ such that $\vec{PP^{\prime}}$ is orthogonal to $l\text{/}\pi$.

If anyone could provide a proof of the statement or an outline of one, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: If you could provide full context, or enough context, it'd be much appreciated.  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and then edit your post to improve it.

Comment: Using translation, WLOG we can assume the line or the plane provided is a closed subspace. Then we can apply the [Hilbert projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) (see the proof in Wikipedia) to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @AlexVong It seems like the proof you provided lies beyond the scope of the course I'm taking. It's an introductory course to linear algebra. Do you know of some proof that falls within those boundaries?

Comment: @S.Doe Which vector space are you working in? Is it $\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: @AlexVong $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'll add that to my question.